# string array declaration in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

Difference between these declarations ?

1.

```
char **strings = {"abc", "bca", "rat", "tar", "far"};
```

2.

```
char *strings[] = {"abc", "bca", "rat", "tar", "far"};
```

3.

```
char strings[][] = {"abc", "bca", "rat", "tar", "far"};
```

Only (2) is a valid declaration. What is the difference between these types and why are (1) and (3) not valid?

Comment: Who said that only 2 is valid?

Comment: If I compile and try to print only 2) was working.

Comment: That depends how you define valid. As a "valid declaration", they are all valid. For a 2 dim-arr, only 2 is valid.

Comment: @SharonJDDorot The C standard defines what is valid. #1 and #3 are invalid.

Comment: @interjay As I said, in order to declare an array of strings, yes it is invalid. But he stated that 1 and 3 are invalid declarations, not invalid array definitions. You most certainly can use all 3 forms, but for different types of operations.

Comment: @SharonJDDorot You can't use them for any type of operation because they are not valid C.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`char **strings` Is a pointer to a pointer to `char`. It's a valid type, but you can't initialize it with an array initializer as you're trying to do.

`char *strings[]` is an array of pointers to `char`, and your initialization of it is valid.

`char strings[][]` is an attempt to make a two-dimensional array, but it's wrong because you have to specify the size of all dimensions except the outermost one (the outermost size can be deduced from the initializer). So this would be valid:

```
char strings[][4] = {"abc", "bca", "rat", "tar", "far"};
```

Answer (score 2):

C99 supports compound literals and thus you can assign an array initializer. So case 1 is also fine with:

```
char **strings = (char *[]) {"abc", "bca", "rat", "tar", "far"};
```

**C99 draft, 6.5.2.5,  Compound literals**

> Constraints
>
> 1 The type name shall specify an object type or an array
> of unknown size, but not a variable length array type.
>
> 2 No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not
> contained within the entire unnamed object specified by the compound
> literal.
>
> 3 If the compound literal occurs outside the body of a function, the
> initializer list shall consist of constant expressions

Answer (score 1):

1) char **strings is a declaration of a pointer to a pointer, it expecteds a attribution of a number not an array of strings.

2) try define the size inside the [] : char *strings[5]={....

3) again, define the size of the array, [x][y] with x = number of elements and y = number of characters of the biggest element